# Dynamic Google Geo Map data

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a page with Geo Map which get the data from a php from ajax. The php returns a json like this:

```
(pt: 500, gb: 763, it: 565, de: 539, fr: 424)
```

I would like to know how can I build the datatable dynamicly reading this array that I already have on the Javascript Side instead of writing on my own:

```
["pt" , 500],
["gb" , 763],
["it" , 565],
["de" , 539],
["fr" , 424]
```

I would like to have an aproach like this http://jsfiddle.net/R6Sh8/ but using it to build the data to feed the map.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your PHP creates a valid JSON:

```
{"pt": 500, "gb": 763, "it": 565, "de": 539, "fr": 424}
```

...you must iterate over the properties of the object(JSON) and create for each property a row by using the uppercase of the property-name and the property-value as column-values:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

      function drawMap() {

        var data  = //json returned from php
                    {"pt": 500, "gb": 763, "it": 565, "de": 539, "fr": 424},
                    //create datatable
            dt    = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        //add columns
        dt.addColumn('string', 'Country');
        dt.addColumn('number', 'amount');
        //add rows
        for(var k in data){
          dt.addRow([k.toUpperCase(),data[k]]);
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geo'));

        chart.draw(dt,{region:150});
      }
```

```css
html,body,#geo{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}
#geo{height:90%}
```

```html
<div id="geo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dr. Molle. I think im almost there...

Im using an array as global variable to store the json.parse from ajax. Then i use console.log after success and I see my data ok. But inside the geomap's function, when im adding the data to the rows of the DataTable from the global variable array, if I use an Alert(k) i see a lot of random data like "path, return value, bubble, srcElement, timeStamp..." and Alert(data[k]) a lot of random numbers

Comment: I'ts not clear what `data` is in your implementation(seem's to be an Event-object), in my demo it's the JSON. There is obviously a conflict with variable-names in your implementation.

Comment: I tried to populate the datatable inside the Ajax success function and it worked. Thank you very much. The code that you first gave me worked perfectly.